# Finding all paths of a certain length in a weighted undirected graph

Tags: c++, c, graph, path

I need to generate all paths that are lesser than or equal to a specified length in a graph (the graph is undirected and it's possible to have cycles). I tried using BFS while keeping track of the distance already traversed but I'm not sure how I would ensure that every path is different.

Note: I know this probably has a very high computational complexity, but I'm not worrying about that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Using BFS is kind of the right way to do so.
But you additionally have to keep track of already found nodes.

There is a simple algorithm from [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) solving this for you

Comment: But since I can have cycles I may need to revisit a node, how would I deal with this?

Comment: Dijkstra gives you the shortest paths to all other nodes beginning from one node, as I understand you the revisiting is neccessary due to a possible shorter path (longer paths would not make sense in my mind atm) so the revisiting is done without setting the node to visited. the node is set a done if and only if the shortest path to this node is already found. otherwise only the "distance information" is updated